# Move for loop into numpy single expression when calling polyfit

Tags: numpy

*Fairly new to numpy/python here, trying to figure out some less c-like, more numpy-like coding styles.*

### Background

I've got some code done that takes a fixed set of x values and multiple sets of corresponding y value sets and tries to find which set of the y values are the "most linear".

It does this by going through each set of y values in a loop, calculating and storing the residual from a straight line fit of those y's against the x's, then once the loop has finished finding the index of the minimum residual value.

...sorry this might make a bit more sense with the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

# set of x values
xs = [1,22,33,54]

# multiple sets of y values for each of the x values in 'xs'
ys = np.array([[1, 22, 3, 4],
               [2, 3, 1, 5],
               [3, 2, 1, 1],
               [34,23, 5, 4],
               [23,24,29,33],
               [5,19, 12, 3]])

# array to store the residual from a linear fit of each of the y's against x
residuals = np.empty(ys.shape[0])

# loop through the xs's and calculate the residual of a linear fit for each
for i in range(ys.shape[0]):
    _, stats = poly.polyfit(xs, ys[i], 1, full=True)
    residuals[i] = stats[0][0]

# the 'most linear' of the ys's is at np.argmin:
print('most linear at', np.argmin(residuals))
```

### Question

I'd like to know if it's possible to "numpy'ize" that into a single expression, something like

residuals = get_residuals(xs, ys)

### ...I've tried:

I've tried the following, but no luck (it always passes the full arrays in, not row by row):

```
# ------ ok try to do it without a loop --------

def wrap(x, y):
    _, stats = poly.polyfit(x, y, 1, full=True)
    return stats[0][0]


res = wrap(xs, ys)   # <- fails as passes ys as full 2D array

res = wrap(np.broadcast_to(xs, ys.shape), ys)  # <- fails as passes both as 2D arrays
```

**Could anyone give any tips on how to numpy'ize that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit) (not to be confused with `numpy.polyfit` which is not interchangable)
:

> x : array_like, shape (M,)
>
> y : array_like, shape (M,) or (M, K)

Your `ys` needs to be transposed to have `ys.shape[0]` equal to `xs.shape`

```
def wrap(x, y):
    _, stats = poly.polyfit(x, y.T, 1, full=True)
    return stats[0]


res = wrap(xs, ys)

res
Out[]: array([284.57337884,   5.54709898,   0.41399317,  91.44641638,
     6.34982935, 153.03515358])
```

Comment: Doh! ...that's what I get for working too late - I should have read the docs again! ...thanks Daniel!

Comment: I don't know which numpy version you use, however, in 1.16.2 the first line of your function produces an value error, since `np.polyfit` returns a tuple of five elements if `full` is `True`. Furthermore, why would you define a function that just calls another function? You could easily call `polyfit` directly. No wrapper needed.

Comment: @MaxPowers I'm at 1.17.3, but I don't think functionality has changed much in years for `polyfit` (Was originally thinking asker needed to update `numpy`, so I checked)

Comment: @MaxPowers Docs for 1.16 also show a 2-tuple output and not a 5-tuple output.  Not sure what's going wrong on your end.

Comment: OK. Thanks for checking. There is obviously a difference between [`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html) and [`numpy.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html), which I imported, that I was not aware of.

Comment: @MaxPowers Yep, there definitely is at that.  Docs of `np.polyfit` suggest using the former, but I can see the confusion.

Comment: Hey all - check if it does what I saw when I tried it.  Above is fitting linearly, so there are 2 coefficients.  For 5 sets of points (K in the docs) it returns 2 arrays of size 5 - so one coeficient per array, number of elements is K.
So it's returning the correct info, but the results aren't perhaps as you'd expect